# sparql binding a url value to a variable

Tags: sparql, fuseki

I have long SPARQL query that needs to use refer to a specific resource at various points throughout the query. This resource is http://scta.info/resource/adt-l14-d1e1535

At the outset of this query, I intend to bind this value to the ?resource. In this way I can use ?resource throughout the query rather than the explicit id. This also makes it easier for me to switch out different ids and test the query on different resources.

This query used to work as when I was running version 2.0 of Fuseki.

After recently upgrading to 4.0 of Fuseki, this query no longer seems to work as intended. Specifically, the initial `BIND (<http://scta.info/resource/adt-l14-d1e1535> as ?resource) .` no longer seems to work. The query goes on forever because `?resource` is treated as free rather than bound variable.

I can confirm this by removing the initial bind statement and then replacing all instances of ?resource with the explicit id: http://scta.info/resource/adt-l14-d1e1535. After this find and replace, the query again works as expected.

Any ideas what is going on? Many thanks for thoughts or ideas.

The full query is below (though the long details of it don't seem to be that important. It is the first Bind statement at the beginning of the query that doesn't seem to be working):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?isRelatedTo ?label ?element ?longTitle ?author ?authorTitle ?isRelatedToRangeStart ?isRelatedToRangeEnd ?parentBlock  
WHERE 
{  
    BIND (<http://scta.info/resource/adt-l14-d1e1535> as ?resource) .
    { 
        ?resource ?o ?isRelatedTo . 
        ?o a <http://scta.info/resource/textRelation> . 
        FILTER (?o != <http://scta.info/property/quotes>) 
        FILTER (?o != <http://scta.info/property/quotedBy>) 
        FILTER (?o != <http://scta.info/property/references>) 
        FILTER (?o != <http://scta.info/property/referencedBy>) ?o <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#label> ?label .  
        ?isRelatedTo a <http://scta.info/resource/expression> . } 
    UNION 
    { 
        { 
            ?resource <http://scta.info/property/structureType> <http://scta.info/resource/structureElement> . 
            BIND (?resource as ?element) 
        } 
        UNION 
        { 
            ?element <http://scta.info/property/isMemberOf> ?resource . 
        } 
        { 
            { 
            ?element <http://scta.info/property/source> ?isRelatedTo .
            FILTER (!isBlank(?isRelatedTo)) .
            } 
            UNION 
            { 
                ?element <http://scta.info/property/source> ?bn . 
                ?bn <http://scta.info/property/source> ?isRelatedTo . 
                ?bn <http://scta.info/property/canonicalRangeStart> ?isRelatedToRangeStart . 
                ?bn <http://scta.info/property/canonicalRangeEnd> ?isRelatedToRangeEnd . } 
                ?element <http://scta.info/property/structureElementType> <http://scta.info/resource/structureElementQuote> . 
                BIND ('quotes' as ?label) . 
            } 
            UNION 
            { 
                { ?element <http://scta.info/property/source> ?isRelatedTo . 
                    FILTER (!isBlank(?isRelatedTo)) . 
                } 
                UNION 
                { 
                    ?element <http://scta.info/property/source> ?bn . 
                    ?bn <http://scta.info/property/source> ?isRelatedTo . 
                    ?bn <http://scta.info/property/canonicalRangeStart> ?isRelatedToRangeStart . 
                    ?bn <http://scta.info/property/canonicalRangeEnd> ?isRelatedToRangeEnd . 
                } 
            ?element <http://scta.info/property/structureElementType> <http://scta.info/resource/structureElementRef> . 
            BIND ('refs' as ?label) . } } UNION { { BIND (?resource as ?element) 
        } 
        UNION 
        { 
            ?element <http://scta.info/property/isMemberOf> ?resource . 
        } 
        { 
            { 
                ?isRelatedTo <http://scta.info/property/source> ?element . 
            } 
            UNION 
            { 
                ?isRelatedTo <http://scta.info/property/source> ?bn . 
                ?bn <http://scta.info/property/source> ?element . 
                ?bn <http://scta.info/property/canonicalRangeStart> ?isRelatedToRangeStart . 
                ?bn <http://scta.info/property/canonicalRangeEnd> ?isRelatedToRangeEnd . 
            } 
            ?isRelatedTo <http://scta.info/property/structureElementType> <http://scta.info/resource/structureElementQuote> . 
            BIND ('isQuotedBy' as ?label) . 
        } 
        UNION 
        { 
            { 
                ?isRelatedTo <http://scta.info/property/source> ?element . 
            } 
            UNION 
            { 
                ?isRelatedTo <http://scta.info/property/source> ?bn . 
                ?bn <http://scta.info/property/source> ?element . 
                ?bn <http://scta.info/property/canonicalRangeStart> ?isRelatedToRangeStart . 
                ?bn <http://scta.info/property/canonicalRangeEnd> ?isRelatedToRangeEnd . 
            } 
            ?isRelatedTo <http://scta.info/property/structureElementType> <http://scta.info/resource/structureElementRef> . 
            BIND ('isReferencedBy' as ?label) . 
            } 
        } 
        ?isRelatedTo <http://scta.info/property/longTitle> ?longTitle .
        ?isRelatedTo <http://scta.info/property/isMemberOf> ?mem . 
        ?mem <http://scta.info/property/level> '1' . 
        OPTIONAL 
        { 
            ?mem <http://www.loc.gov/loc.terms/relators/AUT> ?author . 
            ?author <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title> ?authorTitle 
        } 
        OPTIONAL 
        { 
            ?isRelatedTo <http://scta.info/property/isPartOfStructureBlock> ?parentBlock . 
        } 
    } 
    ORDER BY ?authorTitle LIMIT 200 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Your 2.0 setup relied on a bug. Either syntactically replace ?resource by the URI before sending it. If calling from Jena, there is support for this substitution with `QueryExecution.create().substitution("resource", ...)...`  
Or push the BIND inside each block using ?resource

Comment: Gotcha. @AndyS. Thanks as always :)